# Copy Constructor for dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++

Trying to familiarize myself with the "Rule of 3" and Im having trouble getting a Copy Constructor to work. One of the class private members is returning 0 when it should have a value of 3.

Im not sure as to why when the Copy Constructor function is performed, a value of 0 is supplied to that classes private member. The member in question is `theSize` which is returned via the `size()` function in class.cpp.

**class.h**

```
class Catalog {
public:
    Catalog (int maxCapacity = 100)
    int size() const;
    int capacity() const;
    void add (Book b);
    Catalog(const Catalog& c);
    ~Catalog();
    Catalog& operator= (constCatalog& c) {
        if (this != &c) {
            delete[] books;
            books = new Book[theCapacity];
            *books = *(c.books);
        }
        return *this;
    }
private:
    Book* books;
    int theCapacity;
    int theSize;
};
```

**class.cpp**

```
Catalog::Catalog(int maxCapacity) {
    theCapacity = maxCapacity;
    theSize = 0;
    books = new Book[theCapacity];
}

int Catalog::size() const {
    return theSize();
}

int Catalog::capacity() const {
    return theCapacity;
}

void Catalog::add (Book b)
{
    if (theSize < theCapacity || contains(b.getID())) {
        if (theSize == 0) {
            books[0] = b;
            theSize++;
        }
        else {
            if (!contains(b.getID())) {
                int i = theSize;
                for (; i && b < books[i-1]; --i) {
                    books[i] = books[i - 1];
                }
                books[i] = b;
                for (; i; --i) {
                    books[i - 1] = books[i - 1];
                }       
                theSize++;
            }
            else {
                for (int i = 0; i < theSize; ++i) {
                    if (b == books[i]) {
                        books[i] = b;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Debugging only
        /*for (int i = 0; i < theSize; i++) {
            //cout << books[i] << endl;
        }*/
    }
}

bool Catalog::contains(std::string bookID) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < theSize; ++i)
    {
        if (books[i].getID() == bookID)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

Catalog::Catalog(const Catalog& c) {
    books = new Book[c.theSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < c.theSize; i++) {
        books[i] = c.books[i];
}

Catalog::~Catalog() {
    delete[] books;
}
```

Later in main.cpp when I call `c1.size()` where `c1` is the result of `return c` in another function that through use of the debugger comes from the Copy Constructor and then goes to the Destructor. However, `c1.size()` is returning as `0` though the Copy Constructor `theSize = c.size()` has a value of `3` when stepped through.

**book.cpp**

```
using namespace std;


/**
 * Create a book.
 *
 * @param id the Gutenberg ID for this book
 * @param authorInfo the author of the book
 * @param title the title of the book
 */
Book::Book (std::string theId, std::string authorInfo, std::string theTitle)
    : id(theId), authorName(authorInfo), title(theTitle)
{
}


bool Book::operator< (const Book& b) const
{
  return id < b.id;
}


bool Book::operator== (const Book& b) const
{
  return (id == b.id);
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Book& b)
{
  cout << b.getID() << "\t"
          << b.getAuthor()  << "\t"
          << b.getTitle();
  return out;
}


std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, Book& b)
{
  string line;
  getline (in, line);
  if (!in.good())
    return in;
  int tab1 = line.find ("\t");
  int tab2 = line.find ("\t", tab1+1);
  string id = line.substr(0, tab1);
  string author = line.substr (tab1+1, tab2-tab1-1);
  string title = line.substr(tab2+1);
  b.setID (id);
  b.setAuthor (author);
  b.setTitle (title);
  return in;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
using namespace std;



Catalog readCatalog(const string& fileName)
{
    Catalog c;
    ifstream in (fileName);
    in >> c;
    in.close();
    return c;
}


Catalog mergeCatalogs (const Catalog& cat1, const Catalog& cat2)
{
    Catalog result (cat1.size() + cat2.size());
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < cat1.size() && j < cat2.size())
    {
        Book b1 = cat1.get(i);
        Book b2 = cat2.get(j);
        if (b1.getID() < b2.getID())
        {
            result.add(b1);
            ++i;
        }
        else
        {
            result.add(b2);
            ++j;
        }
    }
    while (i < cat1.size())
    {
        result.add(cat1.get(i));
        ++i;
    }
    while (j < cat2.size())
    {
        result.add(cat2.get(j));
        ++j;
    }
    return result;
}


void mergeCatalogFiles (const string& catalogFile1, const string& catalogFile2)
{
    Catalog c1, c2;
    c1 = readCatalog(catalogFile1);
    cout << catalogFile1 << " contained " << c1.size() << " books." << endl;
    c2 = readCatalog(catalogFile2);
    cout << catalogFile2 << " contained " << c2.size() << " books." << endl;
    Catalog c3 = mergeCatalogs (c1, c2);
    cout <<  "Their merge contains " << c3.size() << " books." << endl;
    cout << c3 << flush;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] <<
                "catalogFile1 catalogFile2" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    string file1 = argv[1];
    string file2 = argv[2];
    mergeCatalogFiles (file1, file2);
    if (Counted::getCurrentCount() == 0)
    {
        cout << "No memory leak detected." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Memory leak detected: " << Counted::getCurrentCount() << endl;
        return -2;
    }
}
```

Comment: `*books = *(c.books);` will copy one element, not the whole array

Comment: @user4581301 so perhaps a `for` loop to copy? Or is there a better way to copy the array?

Comment: For loop or [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Comment: @user4581301 Changed in the above to a for loop; however it is still returning a size of `0`.

Comment: There are a lot of typos and omissions in the above code. You should add `Book` and `main`.

Comment: @user4581301 Such as? I didnt include other .cpp or .h files such as those that define `Book`.

Comment: Your copy constructor also seems to have forgotten about `theCapacity`.

Comment: @user4581301 So in the Copy Constructor, for each member do a `theSize = c.theSize` & `theCapacity = c.theCapacity`? I've tried that and it still says the returned Catalog has a size of 0.

Comment: @user4581301 Apparently the member `theSize` does return correctly after the Copy Constructor, however, immediately afterwards it goes to the Destructor and then the size is lost.

Comment: At this point I'm not even making suggestions to solve the core problem. I'm making suggestions to get the code into good enough shape to look for the problem. I'd expect `theSize = c.size();` to have done the deed, but since it didn't I'd have to recreate your complete test case to see what went wrong. This is why I need `Book` and `main`.

Comment: @user4581301 Is a Destructor normally called immediately after a Copy Constructor?

Comment: @user4581301 you think it's a good habit to copy-construct class members through public getters? :/ Changing the getter will screw internal class logic...

Comment: @iehrlich I'm puzzled. Where did I suggest such a thing? Where did OP do such a thing?

Comment: @user4581301 sorry, misread your `theSize = c.size()` comment :)

Comment: @user4581301 Other code provided now.

Comment: Still incomplete and unable to compile. Your goal should be to produce a [mcve]. The smallest complete test case that demonstrates the problem.  There are a couple reasons for this: One it gives us out here an easily executable program to play with and experiment on and two, very often reducing the problem to the bare essentials exposes the bug to you and makes the question unnecessary. The ability to divide and conquer and reduce a problem to a simple case are absolutely vital skills to the programmer. Or designer of anything.

Comment: @user4581301 You have all the code (except for counted.h/.cpp which do not even apply here...seriously they arent the issue because they are blank). The problem is clear. Step 1: Copy Constructor finish. Step 2: Next function executed is Destructor. Step 3: theSize variable is now 0. Question: Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more like this instead:

```
class Catalog
{
public:
    Catalog (int maxCapacity = 100);
    Catalog(const Catalog& c);
    ~Catalog();

    int size() const;
    int capacity() const;

    void add (const Book &b);
    Book* find(const std::string &bookID) const;

    Catalog& operator= (Catalog c);

private:
    Book* books;
    int theCapacity;
    int theSize;

    void swap(Catalog &c);
};
```

```
#include "class.h"
#include <algorithm>

Catalog::Catalog(int maxCapacity)
{
    theCapacity = maxCapacity;
    theSize = 0;
    books = new Book[theCapacity];
}

Catalog::Catalog(const Catalog& c)
{
    theCapacity = c.theCapacity;
    books = new Book[theCapacity];
    for(int i = 0; i < c.theSize;; ++i)
        books[i] = c.books[i];
    theSize = c.theSize;
}

Catalog::~Catalog()
{
    delete[] books;
}

Catalog& Catalog::operator= (const Catalog &c)
{
    if (this != &c)
        Catalog(c).swap(*this);    
    return *this;
}

void Catalog::swap(Catalog &c)
{
    std::swap(books, c.books);
    std::swap(theSize, c.theSize);
    std::swap(theCapacity, c.theCapacity);
}

int Catalog::size() const
{
    return theSize;
}

int Catalog::capacity() const
{
    return theCapacity;
}

void Catalog::add (const Book &b)
{
    Book *book = find(b.getID());
    if (book) {
        *book = b;
    }
    else if (theSize < theCapacity)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = theSize; i && b < books[i-1]; --i) {
            books[i] = books[i - 1];
        }
        books[i] = b;
        ++theSize;
    }

    // Debugging only
    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < theSize; ++i) {
        cout << books[i] << endl;
    }
    */
}

Book* Catalog::find(const std::string &bookID) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < theSize; ++i)
    {
        if (books[i].getID() == bookID)
            return &books[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That being said, this would be much simpler and easier to manage if you use `std::vector` and STL algorithms.  Let the STL do the hard work for you:

```
#include <vector>

class Catalog
{
public:
    Catalog (int initialCapacity = 100);

    int size() const;
    int capacity() const;

    void add (const Book &b);
    Book* find(const std::string &bookID) const;

private:
    std::vector<Book> books;
};
```

```
#include "class.h"
#include <algorithm>

Catalog::Catalog(int initialCapacity)
{
    books.reserve(initialCapacity);
}

int Catalog::size() const
{
    return books.size();
}

int Catalog::capacity() const
{
    return books.capacity();
}

void Catalog::add (const Book &b)
{
    Book *book = find(b.getID());
    if (book) {
        *book = b;
    }
    else {
        books.insert(std::upper_bound(books.begin(), books.end(), b), b);
    }

    // Debugging only
    /*
    for (Book &book: books) {
        cout << book << endl;
    }
    */
}

Book* Catalog::find(const std::string &bookID) const
{
    auto iter = std::find_if(books.begin(), books.end(), [&bookID](const Book &b){ return (b.getID() == bookID); });
    if (iter != books.end())
        return &*iter;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow rule of zero: use `std::vector<Book>` to replace the array pointer and the size.

Your capacity is a limit on the size.

When at capacity. use equal range to find where to insert, replace last element then std rotate.

Managing both resources and business logic in the same class is bug prone.  Do one thing at a time.

Comment: Definitely the correct answer in the broad sense, but OP has a stated goal of figuring out the Rule of Three.

Comment: @Yakk would prefer to stick with the Rule of Three as it is more applicable to what I am doing in the near future.

Comment: @pasta then write something that *only* manages the resource.  Doing both is shooting yourself in the foot.